# Meaning of the verb from old scientific text "colirt"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I am comparing machine translations of a paragraph from 1890s Beilstein Handbook for an educational paper. There is a word which I cannot find in a dictionary: The topic is on the occurrence of amygdalin (a sugar which causes bitterness in some almonds), where it occurs and how it is extracted.

> Bittere Mandeln werden durch wiederholtes Pressen möglichst vom fetten
>   Oele befreit und dann erst mit 2 Thln. und hier noch einmal mit 1 1⁄2
>   Thln. Alkohol ausgekocht. Die alkoholischen Auszüge filtrirt man, nach
>   dem Erkalten, ab und destillirt den Alkohol ab. Den Retortenrückstand
>   **colirt** man und lässt ihn 24 Stunden stehen, worauf man das
>   ausgeschiedene Amygdalin mit kaltem Alkohol anrührt und dann
>   auspresst. Das Auspressen, nach dem Anrühren mit neuen Mengen Alkohol,
>   wird wiederholt und das Amygdalin endlich aus heißem Alkohol
>   umkrystallisirt.

It seems colirt represents collected or cooled? If this is an old spelling, what is the modern spelling?

Both Google Translate and DeepL do not recognize it. This word is also absent from Beilstein Dictionary (an official dictionary of the handbook users).

Thanks.
EDIT: For the sake of confirmation for the second poster (der bender), I searched Google Scholar for "colirt man" and the context is

[with spelling mistakes from scanned reading:

> 1) Methode in folgender Weise ab: Die zu untersuchenden Massen werden
>   mit Wasser, das vorher mit Phosphorsgure schwach anges~tuert worden
>   ist, bis zu einem dtlnnen Brei versetzt und  1-2 Stunden lang bei
>   60--800 digerirt; darauf **colirt** man dureh ein leinenes Tuch
>
> 2) Nierauf colirt man die Flussigkeit moglichst schnell durch ein
>   leinenes Tuch...

It appears colirt is indeed koliert as suggested.

Comment: what is the topic of this text? Because then it would be possible to look for the process in general and might get an answer. (might be the production of Amygdalin, not sure)

Comment: I added the context.

Comment: While the text is a bit dated, its still some centuries too new for old-high-german. therefore I removed that tag. You would likely not be able to read old high German, and most probably neither would I as native German speaker.

Comment: Evtl interessiert sich noch wer für die [Originalquelle](https://archive.org/stream/handbuchderorgan03beil#page/326/mode/2up/search/colirt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among many other changes, the [German Orthographic Conference of 1901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Orthographic_Conference_of_1901) *([a more detailed article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901) is available in German Wikipedia)* allowed to spell many words with K or Z which was written with C before, depending on their pronunciation. In most cases the version with C still stayed a valid version:

- **C → Z**

  > **c**entral  → **z**entral
  >   so**c**ial → so**z**ial
  >   **c**ivil → **z**ivil
  >   **C**entimeter → **Z**entimeter
  >   **C**itrone → **Z**itrone
- **C → K**

  > **C**ompagnie → **K**ompanie
  >   Reda**c**teur → Reda**k**teur
  >   **C**onto → **K**onto
  >   **C**orpus → **K**orpus
  >   **C**öln → **K**öln
- **both changes in one word**

  > A**cc**ent → A**kz**ent
  >   **C**ir**c**us → **Z**ir**k**us
  >   **C**on**c**ept → **K**on**z**ept
  >   **C**on**c**ert → **K**on**z**ert

The versions with c was used less frequent in the next decades, and today in most of all cases the version with c is no longer valid.

---

I have no evidence for this specific word, but I am very sure, that in 1901 they also changed

> **c**oliren → **k**olieren

(the change of ending *-iren* to *-ieren* was another change from 1901)

Im [PharmaWiki](https://www.pharmawiki.ch/wiki/index.php?wiki=kolieren) you find a description of this word. It says:

> **kolieren** = durch ein Tuch filtern

[Wissen.de](https://www.wissen.de/fremdwort/kolieren) says:

> **kolieren** = durch ein Tuch seihen

Both explanations translate to

> to filter through a cloth

I think that *seihen* is the better matching synonym. Both verbs (*filtern, seihen*) translate to *to filter* in english, but when you use *filtern* then the pores of the filter are so small, that you can't see them with naked eye. When you use *seihen* or *kolieren* then the pores of the filter are much bigger. They are so big, that you can see them with your naked eye.

---

**Etymology**

The word **kolieren, coliren** has its origin in the latin word

> colare = to filter, to sieve

Comment: Interessanterweise kommen in der [Originalquelle](https://archive.org/stream/handbuchderorgan03beil#page/326/mode/2up) beide Schreibweisen vor. Colirt: Seiten 326 + 611, Kolirt: Seiten 540, 1008, 1283

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ist "seihen" ein in Österreich gebräuchliches Wort? Mir war es bis eben genauso unbekannt wie "kolieren", und ohne Kontext hätte ich nicht im Entferntesten erraten, was sie bedeuten.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Ja. Wenn Bauern ihre Kühe gemolken haben, und sie die Milch dann in die großen Kannen umgießen, die später von der Molkerei abgeholt werden, seihen sie dabei die frische Milch durch ein Tuch oder durch ein feines Sieb. Ich kenne das Verb auch aus Kochbüchern, wo oftmals verlangt wird eine Suppe abzuseihen um die klare Flüssigkeit von den Knochen und Gewürzen zu trennen. Auch bei der Zubereitung von Cocktails wird viel geseiht. Mir war aber bisher nicht bewusst, dass dieses Verb nicht im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verbreitet ist. Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seihen

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Das Küchensieb (auch »Teesieb«), das man zum Abseihen verwendet, heißt in einigen ostösterreichischen Dialekten daher auch »Seicherl«. Dieses Wort gehört aber nicht zur Standardsprache und ist auch im Dialekt bereits veraltet.

Comment: Ich zweifle aber daran, dass das Wort »seihen« nur in Österreich verwendet wird. Immerhin ist die Seite Wissen.de, die ja »kolieren« mit »seihen« erklärt keine österreichische, sondern eine deutsche Seite (der Medieninhaber hat seinen Sitz in der Nähe von Stuttgart). Und die Verwendungsbeispiele im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/seihen) sind ausschließlich deutschländische Medien aus Hamburg (die Zeit), Leipzig (Verl. f. d. Frau), Wiesbaden (Falken), Gütersloh (Bertelsmann) und Berlin (die Welt)

Comment: Ich bin aus Hessen und kenne (ab)seihen auch. Und dann drängt sich mir die Frage auf, ob das kolieren mit dem engl. colander (Küchensieb aka Durchschlag) verwandt ist?

Comment: @cbeleites: Ja, das ist der Fall:  Sowohl das deutsche Verb *kolieren* als auch das englische Substantiv *colander* haben ihren Ursprung im lateinischen Verb *colare* = sieben, filtrieren. https://www.etymonline.com/word/colander

Answer (score 9):

This is an alternate (archaic) way of writing

> [kolieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kolieren)

which simply means "to filtrate", or "to strain"

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-36424-6_42

Comment: It also helps, to have a reference of the same period at hand, see [Meyer 1885-92](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=123774).

Answer (score -2):

I guess that this may relate to the word *sammeln* or english *collect.*

Reasons why i think tofros anwser is not applicable is the fact that a already filtered cooled and then destilled substance most likely does not require additional filtering.

Where as the product you get by filtration cooling and destillation of an alcoholic extract is likely to be of solid form and due to the nature of the substance of little quantity (and small scale). And all these particles have to be collected for further processing.

Comment: I think kolieren is correct. See new edits in the post.

Comment: well then just sounded odd from the process point of view